# How to have padding on parent column of nested columns with a CSS Grid (Semantic.gs)

Tags: css, grid, less, grid-system, semantic.gs

I'm using [Semantic.gs](http://semantic.gs) as my grid system. I'm following the [nested column example](http://semantic.gs/examples/nested/nested.html) to try and create what I want while following the grids as much as possible. Given nested column example code from Semantic.gs:

HTML

```
<article>
   <ul>
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
      <li>6</li>
   </ul>
</article>
```

LESS

```
article {
   .column(9);

   ul {
      .row(9);

      li {
         .column(6,9);
      }
   }
}
```

My question is, what's the best way to go about adding padding (ideally the same width as the gutters) to a parent of nested columns, while adhering to the grid system (semantic.gs) as much as possible? **Note, I am using a fixed layout of 960px**.

Here's an example (Photoshop, not exactly according to code above) image of what I'm trying to achieve with the right and left padding on the beige color parent element:

### [image]

**UPDATE:**
Following sandeeps example I was able to do this, but I did fail to mention I am using a 960px grid. Here are my results: http://bit.ly/M5fr5N.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS **box-sizing** property for this. Write like this:

```
#maincolumn {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 20px;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 red;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 1.04167%;
    width: 72.9167%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks sandeep! This does work for the example I gave; however, I failed to mention that I'm using a fixed layout of 960px and this is my result: http://bit.ly/M5fr5N